# Change question in Quiz app few seconds after the answer was selected without "Next" button

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, widget

I am complete beginner with Flutter and Dart and I am stuck on this problem. This is my function for changing question:

```
void _nextQuestion() {
    sleep(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex++;
      answerWasSelected = false;
      tappedAnswer = "";
      renderedTwice = false;
    });

    if (_questionIndex >= _questions.length) {
      _resetQuiz();
    }
  }
```

But, this is my Widget build:

```
return Scaffold(
                  //other code...

                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),   

                  //I want to call it here like this:
                  /*
                  if(renderedTwice){
                      _nextQuestion();
                  }
                  */

                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      child: Text(
                        '${_totalScore.toString()}/${_questions.length}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 40.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ))
               ],
            ),
        ));
      },
    );
```

Now, if I try to call function as I stated up there, I get "The element type 'Set' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.". Also, I can't call it on answerButton press because that's when I call _questionAnswered() function where I specify which answers to turn green or red. I want to make it without pressing "Next Question" button. That means answerButton press changes state and rebuilds the widget, and then widget should wait 3 seconds and call _nextQuestion. I am new in this so maybe solution is simple, but can anyone help me?

I tried to call function in

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Question>?> snapshot) {

//HERE

 return Scaffold(
```

but it would crash.

Comment: can you include your option selection snippet ?

Answer (score 1):

The place you are using for selecting question, add Future.delay() based on your need, then call your `_nextQuestion()` method.

```dart
 onAnswerTapFuntion() async {
   //... yours others operation
   await Future.delay(Duration(seconds:3));
   _nextQuestion();// no need to call sleep inside this method
 }
```